# OpenCV undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I try to build project with OpenCV, i downloaded OpenCV SDK 3.1 from official website, however during building i get error

```
/Users/Mario/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp
Error:(571) undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'
Error:(663) undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
Error:(682) undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::deallocate()'
```

here is my gradle.build, i use `gradle-experimental:0.4.0`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "pl.mariusz.opencv"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 17
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        commandLine '/Users/Mario/Library/Android/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
}
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "source_file"

    cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
    cppFlags.add("-I${file("/Users/Mario/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString())
    cppFlags.add("-I${file("/Users/Mario/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv")}".toString())

    stl = "gnustl_static"//"gnustl_static"//"gnustl_shared"//"stlport_static"
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jni{
            source{
                srcDirs = []
            }
        }
        jniLibs {
            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/Libs']
            }

        }
    }
}
android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
    }
}
```

}

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCVROOT:= /Users/Mario/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE=STATIC
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := source_file.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE := source_file

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-17
```

i tried mix it with shared,static STL with still same error, how can i fix it?

[EDIT]

[image: libopencv]

**[SOLUTION]**

its more like compromise not real solution, but i changed `gradle-experimental:0.4.0` back to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` and added file `gradle.properties` to project root directory with

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: you have to add the opencv libraries to the linker, something like `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d` etc. not sure what their exact names are.

Comment: `Error:error: cannot find -lopencv_core` tried with -libopencv_core and -llibopencv_code with same result, also for `-lopencv_features2d`

Comment: what are the names of your opencv library files and where are they located in your system? They should have names like libopencv_core.*

Comment: I think you need add path to your OpenCV libraries to LD_LIBRARY_PATH (where the linker searches for libraries).

Comment: @Micka i added image what show what name it have and where they are

Comment: @LiMuBei where should i add it

Comment: are you cross-compiling? however, try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/opencv/libs` command before compiling

Comment: same error message? You'll have to use the -lopencv_... version, NOT -llibopencv_... etc.  I'll write an answer, I can't say whether it works, so please dont downvote. It is easier to adjust advices in the answer than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add opencv libraries to your linker. To do that, you have to do 2 things: 1. add the library files; 2. add the library directory.

Try

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl -LlibPath -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core
```

and so an, add all the opencv libraries (or at least the ones you'll need) in this way. -l will automatically assume the "lib" in the filename and the suffix.
The `-L` will tell the linker where to find libraries, so instead of `libPath` please add the absolute path of your opencv library folder. See [how to mention path of libraries in Android.mk file or Application.mk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475944/how-to-mention-path-of-libraries-in-android-mk-file-or-application-mk-file)

Try it and tell me the new error message.

Comment: `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl -L/Users/Mario/AndroidStudioProjects/SteveAR/app/src/main/libs -lopencv_core` leads to `/Users/Mario/Library/Android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld
Error:error: cannot find -lopencv_core`, its looks like it try to find lib in NDK directory

Comment: sorry, I dont have NDK experience, but try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397870/use-external-static-library-in-application-ndk